# Browsers not loading CSS with MediaQuery attribute

Tags: html, css

I have a HTML file from a online banking company that is not displaying correctly on more than one computer (Windows 7 x64 Pro) in my company. The page is a login page of the bank.

I found after extensive research that the problem is the main CSS stylesheet of the page is not being loaded by the browsers (tested on Chrome, IE and Firefox, all updated to lastest versions).

Given the code below:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen, print" href="https://www.ib3.bradesco.com.br/ibpf/conteudo/css/geral/estrutura.css?Versao=6.css" />
```

If I remove the attribute `media="screen, print"` the CSS is loaded and everything works fine.

Does any one knows what is happening? Why the CSS is not loaded with the `media`?

Comment: maybe remove the space after the comma?

Comment: The problem is gone by itself. Don't know the reason. If it happens again I will test the space.

Answer (score 1):

According to [specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/media.html), it's valid. While I have no idea why it doesn't work, here's a practical solution:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://www.ib3.bradesco.com.br/ibpf/conteudo/css/geral/estrutura.css?Versao=6.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="https://www.ib3.bradesco.com.br/ibpf/conteudo/css/geral/estrutura.css?Versao=6.css" />
```

Since only one of the conditions can be true at any one time, it adds almost no overhead, except for the size of `<link />` tag in bytes.

Do note this method wouldn't have been good (in theory) if the conditions could have been both true, since the stylesheet would have been loaded once (second time taken from cache) but parsed twice. It would have worked, of course, but the overhead would have been considerably larger.

---

If you don't have control over the source of the page, the most you could do is inform the owner of the page (the bank) about the problem.